# Cant use add_reaction discord.py (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji

Tags: discord, discord.py, http-status-code-400, httpexception

I am trying to create a discord bot that analyzes images and returns an appropriate emoji and that works fine but whenever I try to use it as a reactable I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\noahs\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\noahs\OneDrive\Desktop\Bot\bot.py", line 238, in on_message
    await message.add_reaction(reacta)
  File "C:\Users\noahs\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\message.py", line 1220, in add_reaction
    await self._state.http.add_reaction(self.channel.id, self.id, emoji)
  File "C:\Users\noahs\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji
```

The code I am executing is this:

```
   file_ = filename
   print("classifying")
   reaction = classify(file_)
   reaction = str(reaction)
   reaction = (reaction.encode('unicode-escape').decode('ASCII'))
   reaction = reaction[:-2]
   print(reaction)
   await message.add_reaction(reaction)
```

and the code works perfectly always outputting something like this:

```
classifying
\U0001f30f
```

and I get the Unicode of a valid emoji but when I use it with the add_reaction corountine I get the error, I have no idea what could be causing this as I have a valid Unicode emoji as a string specified but I've spent hours fiddling and I just can't figure it out.
(note: please do not suggest using the raw emoji that causes an entirely different htttp error)

Comment: You might be able to use `"\N{EARTH GLOBE ASIA-AUSTRALIA}"` instead

Comment: When you print Unicode emoji it should output the emoji as , not `\U0001f30f`. Could you give me the output of line `reaction = classify(file_)` and its type (with `print`)?

Comment: I am aware it should output that, and it does if I don’t change it to Unicode but when I try to use the emoji output as a reaction it give me the 405: Method Not Allowed error which I also don’t understand as in both cases I have a valid emoji but I can’t seem to use it with discord.py

Comment: @RiveN if you'd like more information about the code I'm happy to add you on discord and stream the code running, I'm just so confused about this problem and I cant seem to figure out the issue.